# Set dynamic variable in gitlab.yml build script

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, yaml, devops

What I would like to accomplish is to be able to have a variable that represents the date in the format of YYYY.MM.DD.FFFF (year.month.day.seconds) that I can access and use in various parts of my build script.  I think this is possible using powershell and the variables block in the build script but it doesn't seem to want to actually execute the command.  I'm flexible on how I get to the end goal, doesn't have to powershell nor be in the variables block, in-case I'm not on the right track here.  Basically what I am trying to do now is

```
variables:
  version: Get-Date -Format yyyy.MM.dd.fffff
```

Then in a script block reference the variable

```
- echo %version%
```

Of course when I reference this variable it outputs the "Get-Date -Format yyyy.MM.dd.fffff" verbatim.  I've tried various mutations of this, such as prepending the variable with "powershell -command" and calling it in a script block via $env:version but I am having no luck getting the date to output.  Hopefully I'm just missing something silly...but perhaps what I'm trying to do can't be done here and I am just wasting my time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works if you have a batch runner (as we do)

```
  before_script:
- FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('powershell Get-Date -Format yyyy.MM.dd.HHmmss') DO SET VERSION=%%i
- ECHO The version is %VERSION%
```